# How to trigger Firebase cloud functions to update a field by a condition once a day and send push notification to Android client

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm totally new to Cloud Functions of Firebase and I need a little support.

I would to trigger two cloud functions, one that run once a day and the other one that sends a push notification to my Android client app.

Just let me write a little representation of my Cloud Firestore (not Realtime Database), IDs are auto generated by Firebase:

```
/users
  /uId1
    /myitems
      /adId1
        /myinterestedusers
          /uId2
      /adId2
        ...
  /uId2
    ...
/itemsonsale
  /uId1_adId1
  /uId1_adId2
  /uId2_adId1
```

I perform all the operations to populate and update the db correctly in the client side Android app written in koltin but I need these more things.

The function I would trigger once a day has to update a field if a string in a `adIdXX` document, representing the date, is expired and then it should be change another field in the same documentReference with string "EXPIRED". All this operation must be done for each docRef that have a `adIdXX` in all the db, so for each `/myitems/{id}` of each `/users/{id}` and for each `/itemsonsale/{id}`.

The other one, that must be send a push notification to my client, has to listen for the same status as above but when it will be "SOLD" it must notify the interested users, so for example I thought that it's enough to watch the `/itemsonsale` collection and for each `{id}` document check this field and then following this path to send notification to that user in `/users`:

```
/itemsonsale/{id} checks fields "status"=="SOLD"
  take ownerID
  go to /users/ownerIdXX/myitems/adIdXX/myinterestedusers/{id}
  and send a push notification for each of those {id} documents in that collection
```

NOTE: uIdXX_adIdXX stands for ownerId_adId

Hope I explained my idea and wait for support cause I have no idea of where to start...

EDITED: after a few hours I'm stuck on this code below...anyone can tell me how can I continue?

```
exports.checkItemsSold = 
functions.firestore.document('/itemsonsale/{id}')
.onUpdate((change, context) => {
  const after = change.after.data()
  const before = change.before.data()
  const oldStatus = before.itemStatus
  const newStatus = after.itemStatus
  console.log(`Item's owner replaced ${oldStatus} with ${newStatus}\n`)
  if(newStatus === "SOLD")
  {
     //here I have to send push to interested users
  }
})


exports.checkItemsExpirationDate = 
functions.firestore.document('/users/{uid}/myitems/{iid}') //but really all the db so also /itemsonsale/{id}
.onUpdate((change, context) => {
  const after = change.after.data()
  const before = change.before.data()
  //I'm not sure if onUpdate() is the right way for this task
  //but this function has to perform the check of date expiration
  //from 'expiryDate' field and in case of it's expired must set
  //"EXPIRED" to 'itemStatus' field. All for each item in the db, once a day
  console.log('Updated info from data: ', after)

});
```

Comment: Have you tried any code for your Firebase Cloud Function?

Comment: I didn't know anything 5 hours ago when I asked the question, now maybe yeh... I tried to write some code, after I set the all work environment, but I'm stuck on it...I don't know how to perform the right things even if I read the official docs. Anyway I edited the answer with my attempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking your code I can say that at least this section is ok:

```
exports.checkItemsSold = 
functions.firestore.document('/itemsonsale/{id}')
.onUpdate((change, context) => {
  const after = change.after.data()
  const before = change.before.data()
  const oldStatus = before.itemStatus
  const newStatus = after.itemStatus
  console.log(`Item's owner replaced ${oldStatus} with ${newStatus}\n`)
  if(newStatus === "SOLD")
  {
     //here I have to send push to interested users
  }
})
```

The main issue with the second one is that the triggers only happens when there is an `update`, `write`, `delete` or `create` event. As you're not waiting for an `update` or any of the other events but checking the status of some fields on your DB I would say that you can create an [scheduled function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions). [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions#write_a_scheduled_function) you will find an example code which is something like this for your case:

```
//Let's supose that you want to check the expiration date every day in the first minute of the day
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

let db = admin.firestore();
exports.scheduledFunctionCrontab = functions.pubsub.schedule('1 0 * * *')
  .timeZone('America/New_York') // Users can choose timezone - default is America/Los_Angeles
  .onRun((context) => {
  //Here goes your code to change the status of the field needed in your DB to Expired.
  return null;
});
```

Sorry if there is a mistake with the code but I'm not good with NodeJS. Good luck!

Comment: yeh, ok! But, the only problem with that approach is billing information that are missing in my account...since it's a college project I don't want to use it...anyway I'll try it